# How does All for One Impact Recoil quirk works?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Supposedly All for One Impact Recoil quirk "enables All For One to completely reflect the impact of an attack back to the attacker". This seems to be the quirk used in season 3 episode 10 in the battle of All for One with All Might. If he can revert the impact of an attack back to the attacker, to use it all the time wouldn't turn the user invincible? Then why All for One doesnt use it all the time, does it have any flaws or drawbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to completely reflect the impact

From where did you take this information? According to the [Boku no Hero Academia Wikia](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Impact_Recoil) the physical impact gets reversed, but not "completely reflected".

So, it wouldn't turn the user invincible, because the user is still to some degree affected by the attack (as written in [Boku no Hero Academia Wikia](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Impact_Recoil)):

> However, this Quirk does not seem to cancel the impact completely

That is probably why All For One uses Gran Torino as a shield instead of taking the punch himself.

Comment: From the same wikia, other page http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/All_For_One

Comment: Interesting. Seems like different people wrote those explanations of the same quirk. But the fact, that he used another person as a shield still implies, that there are some negative effects from using the quirk, hence no invincibility.